# Spring Hibernate Передача объекта методом post через форму

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, form

Есть простая связка объектов в БД: department и employee (1 к n)

Модели:

```
@Entity
public class Department implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3532377236419382984L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int departmentId;
@NotEmpty(message = "The department name must not be null")
private String departmentName;
@NotEmpty(message = "The department description must not be null")
private String departmentDescription;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Employee> employeeList;

public int getDepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(int departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

public String getDepartmentName() {
    return departmentName;
}

public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

public String getDepartmentDescription() {
    return departmentDescription;
}

public void setDepartmentDescription(String departmentDescription) {
    this.departmentDescription = departmentDescription;
}

public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
    return employeeList;
}

public void setEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {
    this.employeeList = employeeList;
}
}


@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3532377236419382983L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int employeeId;
@NotEmpty (message = "The employee name must not be null")
private String employeeName;
@Length(min = 7, max = 12, message = "The employee phone must mot be less then 7 numbers and more then 12 numbers")
private String employeePhone;
@NotEmpty (message = "The employee role must not be null")
private String employeeRole;

@NotNull(message = "The employee department must not be null")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "departmentId")
private Department department;

public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public String getEmployeeName() {
    return employeeName;
}

public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
}

public String getEmployeePhone() {
    return employeePhone;
}

public void setEmployeePhone(String employeePhone) {
    this.employeePhone = employeePhone;
}

public String getEmployeeRole() {
    return employeeRole;
}

public void setEmployeeRole(String employeeRole) {
    this.employeeRole = employeeRole;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}
}
```

Есть контроллер, который добавляет новых employee:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/employeeBase/addEmployee")
public String addEmployee(Model model){
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    List<Department> departmentList = departmentDao.getAllDepartments();
    Department department = new Department();
    employee.setDepartment(department);
    model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
    model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentList);

    return "addEmployee";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/employeeBase/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployeePost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        List<Department> departmentList = departmentDao.getAllDepartments();
        model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentList);
        return "addEmployee";
    }

    employeeDao.addEmployee(employee);

    return "redirect:/admin/employeeBase";
}
```

И сама форма:

```
 <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/employeeBase/addEmployee" method="post" commandName="employee" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <form:input path="employeeName" id="name" class="form-Control" />
            <form:errors path="employeeName" cssStyle="color:#ff0000;" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="department">Department: </label>
            <c:forEach var="department" items="${departmentList}">
                <form:radiobutton path="department" id="department" value="department" label="${department.departmentName}" required="required"/>
                <form:errors path="department" cssStyle="color:#ff0000;" />
            </c:forEach>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <form:input path="employeePhone" id="phone" class="form-Control" />
            <form:errors path="employeePhone" cssStyle="color:#ff0000;" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="employeeRole">Role</label>
            <form:input path="employeeRole" id="role" class="form-Control" />
            <form:errors path="employeeRole" cssStyle="color:#ff0000;" />
        </div>
        <br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <a href="<c:url value="/admin/employeeBase" />" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>

    </form:form>
```

Смысл таков: когда администратор хочет добавить нового сотрудника. он видит форму обычных полей и список радиобаттонов (департаментов). Департамент у нас отдельная сущность.

**Вопрос: как вместе с обычными данными employee передать department?**

Сейчас вылетает ошибка:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type com.taskmanager.model.Department for property department; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
>   type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [com.taskmanager.model.Department] for property department: no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 0):

добавить в класс Employee поле Long departamentId с соответствующей колонкой в БД. С соответствующей REFERENCES на ID департамента.  При регистрации работника указывается ID департамента, либо отображать название департамента сразу в форме.

Comment: Выходит, мы должны хранить сам замапленный объект department (в котором есть id) и еще создавать отдельное поле под это id? Это точно верное решение? К сожалению, пока нигде не могу найти пример подобного реквеста  с кастомными полями (кругом с простыми полями)

Comment: у вас есть геттер сущности public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}, берите из него. Смотрите примеры на тему связи "Один-ко-Многим"

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в маппинге радиобаттонов на департмент

Решение:

```
<form:radiobutton path="department.departmentId" id="department" value="${department.departmentId}" label="${department.departmentName}" required="required"/>
```